# Linux Mint + FriendlyARM 2440: Cannot install and execute cross-compiler and toolschain (arm-linux-gcc-4.4.3.tar.gz)

Tags: compiling, arm

I have installed Linux Mint 17 on my 32-bit laptop and bought a FriendlyARM Mini2440 development board to do some basic programming and learn concepts of Linux.

However, I couldn't find any documentation on how to install the cross-compiler and toolchain for FriendlyARM Mini2440 on Linux Mint (I found it for Ubuntu, though). I am using [this tutorial](https://alselectro.wordpress.com/category/friendly-arm-mini2440/) to start my system and have followed all the steps.

My problem is that while I am able to install and execute the cross-compiler and toolchain correctly for the first time, after restarting, when I issue the command `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-cc –v`, it gives me an error.

How can I get FriendlyARM Mini2440 to work on Linux Mint?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please take a moment and read through our [help] or take the [tour] to understand how the site works. Each question should only be about a single issue, separate issues should be posted as different questions. I have edited your question and removed the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link  https://alselectro.wordpress.com/category/friendly-arm-mini2440/
they suggest pasting the following line into `/root/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/FriendlyArm/toolschain/4.4.3/bin
```

However, I didn't have the `/root/.bashrc` file in my Linux Mint, so I was getting an error for `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-cc –v`.

After much searching, I found that I can paste the path `/root/.profile/` instead.

After doing this, the arm compiler is initialized on start-up and seems to be working fine now.

Although the procedures in the link are for FriendlyARM2440 + Ubuntu, I have tested all of them for Linux Mint 17, and except for this small change, all seem to work fine.

Comment: Note that `/root/.bashrc` simply doesn't exist by default. You could have just as easily created it yourself but, in any case, `~/.profile` is better. However, you really shouldn't be doing this as root. You should do it as a regular user and use your `~/.profile` file instead.

Comment: Can you provide some references regarding FriendlyARM2440 + Linux Mint ?? For eg. sample examples, rtos, cross compiler etc.